# Jbuilder with conditional generate empty keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

This is my public.json.jbuilder

```
json.(@plantao, :data_referencia, :data_fim)

json.plantoes_locais @plantao.plantao_lotacoes do |plantao_local|

  json.plantao_local(plantao_local,
    :periodo_inicio, :periodo_fim, :servidor, :lotacao, :contato
  ) if plantao_local.dentro_periodo?

end
```

When my JSON is generated, several empty {} are generated at the end of the file, because of my conditional

```
{
  "data_referencia": "2014-12-15T18:00:00.000-02:00",
  "data_fim": "2014-12-18T08:00:00.000-02:00",
  "plantoes_locais": [
    {
      "plantao_local": {
        "periodo_inicio": "2014-12-16T08:00:00.000-02:00",
        "periodo_fim": "2014-12-17T08:00:00.000-02:00",
        "servidor": null,
        "lotacao": null,
        "contato": null
      }
    },
    {
      "plantao_local": {
        "periodo_inicio": "2014-12-16T08:00:00.000-02:00",
        "periodo_fim": "2014-12-17T08:00:00.000-02:00",
        "servidor": null,
        "lotacao": null,
        "contato": null
      }
    },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

How can I delete these empty {}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jbuilder github page says you can use:

```
json.ignore_nil!
```

[source](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

Answer (score 2):

Delete empty hash with [`delete_if()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) and [`empty?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-i-empty-3F) . Something like this should work:

```
json.(@plantao, :data_referencia, :data_fim)

json.plantoes_locais @plantao.plantao_lotacoes do |plantao_local|

  json.plantao_local(plantao_local,
    :periodo_inicio, :periodo_fim, :servidor, :lotacao, :contato
  ) if plantao_local.dentro_periodo?

end.delete_if(&:empty?)
```